# How to allow one QUERY in graphql to be anonymous?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am new to GraphQL and I stumbled upon an issue on allowing one API call to be called anonymously.

The REST API (in C# Code) for getting a list is already tagged with [AllowAnonymous]
This also works when tried in swagger.

When implementing the query in GraphQL - Apollo Server, where should I put the code of exempting this API call to not pass authorization token?

Comment: help us, help you, please put in some code so that we can have a look.